# Get distinct count of values in single row in Pyspark DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I'm trying to split comma separated values in a string column to individual values and count each individual value.

The data I have is formatted as such:

```
+--------------------+
|                tags|
+--------------------+
|cult, horror, got...|
|            violence|
|            romantic|
|inspiring, romant...|
|cruelty, murder, ...|
|romantic, queer, ...|
|gothic, cruelty, ...|
|mystery, suspense...|
|            violence|
|revenge, neo noir...|
+--------------------+
```

And I want the result to look like

```
+--------------------+-----+
|                tags|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|cult                |    4|
|horror              |   10|
|goth                |    4|
|violence            |   30|
...
```

The code I've tried that hasn't worked is below:

```
data.select('tags').groupby('tags').count().show(10)
```

I also used a countdistinct function which also failed to work.

I feel like I need to have a function that separates the values by comma and then lists them  but not sure how to execute them.

Comment: What are you counting? What does count=4 mean for "cult" above?

Comment: It means throughout the column 'tags' cult appeared 4 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [split()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html) to split strings, then [explode()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html). Finally, groupby and count:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[
    ["cult,horror"],
    ["cult,comedy"],
    ["romantic,comedy"],
    ["thriler,horror,comedy"],
], schema=["tags"])

df = df \
  .withColumn("tags", F.split("tags", pattern=",")) \
  .withColumn("tags", F.explode("tags"))

df = df.groupBy("tags").count()

[Out]:
+--------+-----+
|tags    |count|
+--------+-----+
|romantic|1    |
|thriler |1    |
|horror  |2    |
|cult    |2    |
|comedy  |3    |
+--------+-----+
```

Comment: I actually just checked and I'm getting repeated values in tags showing up more than once with a different count value. For example, 'magic realism' is showing up with a count of 4 and then again with a count of 50.

Comment: Check if there is any extra space in that tag name. e.g. `df = df.withColumn("tag_check", F.format_string("_%s_", df.tags))`